lb4 on cloudlinux hosting - failed to spawn app
I'm trying to run a lb4 app on a web hosting. The hosting service uses DirectAdmin (v.1.668) on CloudLinux (v.7.11.11-1) with nodejs-selector (Phusion Passenger, 6.0.20).
I'm following the guide https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Getting-started.html to create a simple lb4 app. All files and directories are uploaded to the server and I can run npm install och startup the app in DirectAdmin without any error but when I try to access to app the server response that it could not spawn the app.
Reading https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/nodejs/reverse_port_binding.html it looks like for Passenger to spawn it it needs to invoke http.Server.listen() once and only once, and make it pass 'passenger' as argument. Also no port nr should be set.
As I understand lb4 uses loopback/rest which will call http.Server.listen().
How can I bypass it so it calls 'http.Server..listen('passenger')'? I have tried pass 'passenger' string in the config object in the index.js file but did not work.
This is how my index.js file looks like:
"use strict";
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
       PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}
var _a;
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.main = void 0;
const tslib_1 = require("tslib");
const application_1 = require("./application");
tslib_1.__exportStar(require("./application"), exports);
async function main(options = {}) {
    const app = new application_1.GettingStartedApplication(options);
    await app.boot();
    await app.start();
    const url = app.restServer.url;
    console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);
    console.log(`Try ${url}/ping`);
    return app;
}
exports.main = main;
if (require.main === module) {
    // Run the application
    const config = {
        rest: {
            port: +((_a = process.env.PORT) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : 3000),
        //host: process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1',
            host: 'passenger',
        // The `gracePeriodForClose` provides a graceful close for http/https
            // servers with keep-alive clients. The default value is `Infinity`
            // (don't force-close). If you want to immediately destroy all sockets
            // upon stop, set its value to `0`.
            // See https://www.npmjs.com/package/stoppable
            gracePeriodForClose: 5000,
            openApiSpec: {
                // useful when used with OpenAPI-to-GraphQL to locate your application
                setServersFromRequest: true,
            },
        },
    };
    main(config).catch(err => {
        console.error('Cannot start the application.', err);
        process.exit(1);
    });
}
```

